# How to get the cookie from a GET response?

Tags: http, cookies, rust, hyper

I am writing a function that makes a GET request to a website and returns the response cookie:

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate hyper;
extern crate tokio_core;

use tokio_core::reactor::Core;
use hyper::Client;
use std::error::Error;
use hyper::header::Cookie;
use futures::future::Future;

fn get_new_cookie() -> Result<String, Box<Error>> {
    println!("Getting cookie...");
    let core = Core::new()?;
    let client = Client::new(&core.handle());
    println!("Created client");

    let uri = "http://www.cnn.com".parse().expect("Cannot parse url");
    println!("Parsed url");
    let response = client.get(uri).wait().expect("Cannot get url.");
    println!("Got response");
    let cookie = response
        .headers()
        .get::<Cookie>()
        .expect("Cannot get cookie");
    println!("Cookie: {}", cookie);

    Ok(cookie)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", get_new_cookie());
}
```

This doesn't work; it is stuck on the `client.get(...)` string. The output I'm getting is:

```
Getting cookie...
Created client
Parsed url
```

and after that nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong and how I can change it so it'd work?

Comment: How is this related to cookies? The problem is in `let response` line which is not related to cookies at all.

Comment: The cookies returned by the server are in the `Set-Cookie` header; the `Cookie` header is used in requests to send cookies to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Stefan points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47854518/155423), by calling `wait`, you are putting the thread to sleep until the future has completed. However, that thread needs to run the event loop, so you've just caused a deadlock. Using [`Core::run`](https://docs.rs/tokio-core/0.1.11/tokio_core/reactor/struct.Core.html#method.run) is more correct.

As [Francis Gagné points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47853778/hyper-how-to-get-the-cookie-from-get-response#comment82675397_47853778), the "Cookie" header is used to send a cookie *to the server*. [`SetCookie`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.11.9/hyper/header/struct.SetCookie.html) is used to send a cookie *to the client*. It also returns a vector of all the cookies together:

```
fn get_new_cookie() -> Result<String, Box<Error>> {
    println!("Getting cookie...");
    let mut core = Core::new()?;

    let client = Client::new(&core.handle());
    println!("Created client");

    let uri = "http://www.cnn.com".parse().expect("Cannot parse url");
    println!("Parsed url");

    let response = core.run(client.get(uri)).expect("Cannot get url.");
    println!("Got response");

    let cookie = response
        .headers()
        .get::<SetCookie>()
        .expect("Cannot get cookie");
    println!("Cookie: {:?}", cookie);

    Ok(cookie.join(","))
}
```

---

However, if you only want a synchronous API, use [Reqwest](https://crates.io/crates/reqwest) instead. It is built on top of Hyper:

```
extern crate reqwest;

use std::error::Error;
use reqwest::header::SetCookie;

fn get_new_cookie() -> Result<String, Box<Error>> {
    let response = reqwest::get("http://www.cnn.com")?;

    let cookies = match response.headers().get::<SetCookie>() {
        Some(cookies) => cookies.join(","),
        None => String::new(),
    };

    Ok(cookies)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", get_new_cookie());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See the [documentation for the `wait` method](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.17/futures/future/trait.Future.html#method.wait):

> **Note**: This method is not appropriate to call on event loops or similar
>   I/O situations because it will prevent the event loop from making
>   progress (this blocks the thread). This method should only be called
>   when it's guaranteed that the blocking work associated with this
>   future will be completed by another thread.

`Future::wait` is already [deprecated in the `tokio-reform`](https://github.com/alexcrichton/futures-rs/pull/634) branch.

I'd recommend to design the full application to deal with async concepts (i.e. `get_new_cookie` should take a `Handle` and return a `Future`, not allocating its own event loop).

You could run the request with [`Core::run`](https://docs.rs/tokio-core/0.1.11/tokio_core/reactor/struct.Core.html#method.run) like this:

```
let response = core.run(client.get(uri)).expect("Cannot get url.");
```

Answer (score 0):

### reqwest 0.11 (and perhaps earlier) update

In the `get_new_cookie` function, I believe the code snippet to retrieve the cookies from a `reqwest::Response` goes something like:

```rust
// returns Option<&HeaderValue>

response.headers().get(http::header::SET_COOKIE)
```