# Using Tokio's mpsc and oneshot leads to deadlock

Tags: rust, deadlock, rust-tokio

I want to write a SOCKS server which selects one of several internet gateways depending on the destination as requested by the client. The general flow is

1. Perform SOCKS5 negotiation and derive the address information from client
2. Request an internal server to select the internet gateway and the destination's IP
3. Connect and do the communication

For this internal server, a Tokio task is spawned which waits on a mpsc queue. The received messages should contain the SOCKS5 address info and the tx side of a oneshot channel to give back the result.

Another Tokio task just periodically queries the internal server:

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate tokio_core;
extern crate tokio_timer;

use std::time;
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};
use std::fmt::Debug;
use tokio_core::reactor::{Core, Interval};
use tokio_timer::wheel;
use futures::{Future, Sink, Stream};
use futures::sync::{mpsc, oneshot};

type MsgRequest<A, E> = oneshot::Sender<Result<A, E>>;
type FutRequest<A, E> = mpsc::Sender<MsgRequest<A, E>>;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Responder<A, E> {
    fut_tx: FutRequest<A, E>,
}

impl<A: 'static, E: 'static> Responder<A, E>
where
    E: Debug,
{
    fn query(&self) -> Result<A, E> {
        println!("enter query");
        let (res_tx, res_rx) = oneshot::channel::<Result<A, E>>();
        println!("send query");
        let fut_tx = self.fut_tx.clone();
        let res = fut_tx
            .send(res_tx)
            .then(|tx| {
                if let Ok(_tx) = tx {
                    println!("Sink flushed");
                }
                res_rx
            })
            .and_then(|x| Ok(x))
            .wait()
            .unwrap();
        res
    }
}

impl<A: 'static, E: 'static> Clone for Responder<A, E> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Responder {
            fut_tx: self.fut_tx.clone(),
        }
    }
}

fn resolve(tx: oneshot::Sender<Result<u8, String>>) -> Result<(), ()> {
    println!("resolve");
    let delay = time::Duration::from_secs(10);
    wheel()
        .build()
        .sleep(delay)
        .then(|_| tx.send(Ok(0)))
        .wait()
        .unwrap();
    println!("resolve answered");
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    let mut lp = Core::new().unwrap();
    let handle = lp.handle();

    let (fut_tx, fut_rx) = mpsc::channel::<MsgRequest<u8, String>>(100);
    let resolver = fut_rx.for_each(|msg| resolve(msg));
    handle.spawn(resolver);

    let responder = Responder { fut_tx };

    let server = Interval::new_at(Instant::now(), Duration::new(2, 0), &handle)
        .unwrap()
        .for_each(move |_| {
            println!("Call query for_each");
            let rx = responder.clone();
            let _res = rx.query();
            Ok(())
        })
        .map_err(|_| ());
    handle.spawn(server);

    loop {
        lp.turn(None);
    }
}
```

Using Cargo.toml dependencies:

```
[dependencies]
futures = "0.1"
tokio-core = "0.1"
tokio-timer = "0.1"
```

This code deadlocks. The output is:

```
Call query for_each
enter query
send query
Sink flushed
```

Expected output is:

```
Call query for_each
enter query
send query
Sink flushed
resolve
resolve answered
Call query for_each
enter query
send query
Sink flushed
resolve
resolve answered
....
```

This indicates that the request with the `tx` end has been successfully sent to the internal server but the internal server does not process it. From my understanding, mpsc and oneshot can be used to transfer between tasks and not only threads, so the containing thread should not deadlock as it does.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the cookie from a GET response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47853778/how-to-get-the-cookie-from-a-get-response)

Comment: In short: don't use `wait()`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with wait(). Apparently this future system from Tokio is difficult to master. If there would be a task-blocking and not thread-blocking wait(), then this would be much better. Looking to nightly with async/await is promising to have a sound implementation finally.

Comment: task-but-not-thread-blocking wait is usually named "green threads" or "lightweight threads", and requires allocating separate stacks and switching between them (sometimes called "coroutine"). async/await and tokio/futures are exactly the opposite approach. (although async/await looks similar to the "task-but-not-thread-blocking" thing it is implemented differently.)

Comment: Now I understand futures much better. As I come from python 3 with await/async, this seems not to be a good starting point to understand rust's future concept.

Answer (score 0):

After having read [Aaron's blog](https://aturon.github.io/blog/2016/09/07/futures-design/), the concept of futures is now more clear. My first approach is not demand-driven and thus inadequate. The function resolve() should actually return a future and not a result.

In order to close this question appropriately, here is my modified, further reduced minimal example to show the concept:

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate tokio_core;
extern crate tokio_timer;

use std::time;
use std::time::{Instant,Duration};
use tokio_core::reactor::{Core, Interval};
use tokio_timer::wheel;
use futures::{Future,Stream,Sink};
use futures::sync::{oneshot,mpsc};

type MsgRequest<A,E> = oneshot::Sender<Result<A,E>>;

fn main() {
    let mut lp = Core::new().unwrap();
    let handle = lp.handle();

    let (fut_tx, fut_rx) = mpsc::channel::<MsgRequest<u8,String>>(100);
    let handle2 = handle.clone();
    let resolver = fut_rx.and_then(move |tx| {
            println!("Got query...wait a bit");
            let delay = time::Duration::from_secs(5);
            handle2.spawn({
                wheel().build().sleep(delay)
                    .then(move |_|{
                        println!("Answer query");
                        tx.send(Ok(0)).unwrap();
                        println!("query answered");
                        Ok(())
                })
            });
            Ok(())
        })
        .for_each(|_| {Ok(())});
    handle.spawn(resolver);

    let server = Interval::new_at(Instant::now(),
                                Duration::new(2,0),&handle).unwrap()
            .then(move |_| {
                let fut_tx = fut_tx.clone();
                let (res_tx, res_rx) = oneshot::channel::<Result<u8,String>>();
                println!("send query");
                fut_tx.send(res_tx)
                    .then( |tx|{
                        if let Ok(_tx) = tx { println!("Sink flushed"); }
                        res_rx
                    })
            })
            .for_each(|res| {
                println!("Received result {:?}",res);
                Ok(())
            }).map_err(|_| ());
    handle.spawn(server);

    loop {
        lp.turn(None);
    }
}
```

It outputs as expected:

```
send query
Sink flushed
Got query...wait a bit
Answer query
query answered
Received result Ok(0)
send query
Sink flushed
Got query...wait a bit
Answer query
query answered
Received result Ok(0)
...
```